# STL sort with retaining the original order

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I'd like to reverse-sort a vector of strings by size, with the constraint that if there are 2 strings of equal length, I'd like them to retain their original order. For eg: sorting the following set of strings :-

```
aab
aac
aacghgh
aabghgh
```

should yield :-

```
aacghgh
aabghgh
aab
aac
```

Currently I'm doing the sorting as follows :-

```
struct comp_functor {
    bool operator()(const string& s1, const string& s2) {
        return s1.size() > s2.size();
    }
};

struct comp_functor c;
vector<string> vecs;
sort(vecs.begin(), vecs.end(), c);
```

Is there any way to specify in the overloaded method that I want to retain the original ordering if they have the same length? If not, what would be the best way to use STL libraries to solve this problem?

Comment: [std::stable_sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort)

Comment: Just change the condition to >= and it should work

Comment: @Ashkan -- No.  Sorting requires a *strict-weak_order*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [`std::stable_sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort).
It preserves the order of elements which are considered equal.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want equivalent elements to change order, then don't use `std::sort`. Use [std::stable_sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort) instead - it exists exactly because it has the property of not reordering equivalent elements.